# Is this a typescript function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I was reading the [vue-next source code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/master/packages/runtime-core/src/hydration.ts#L39), and came across a line I had a little trouble with.  I figure this is because I am new to typescript.

Is this a function? What is it doing?

```js
const isComment = (node: Node): node is Comment =>
  node.nodeType === DOMNodeTypes.COMMENT
```

Comment: it is called typeguard

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The `node is Comment` syntax is used to relay the fact that the function's purpose is to check if the passed-in parameter is of a specific type, "Comment" in this case.

Comment: This is not correct. See the answer from Brahim.

Answer (score 1):

`node is Comment` is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), where `node`  must be the name of a parameter from the current function signature, each time `isComment` is called the Typescript narrows the Node type to the `Comment` one if the parameter is compatible with `Node` type